# MFMailComposeViewController get email body

Tags: ios, xcode, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I can detect sending in the `MFMailComposeViewController's` delegate method

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
```

How can i get text of this message?

I need it for analytics.

Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think, you can get the text from delegate method.

Comment: You can derive the class from MFMailComposerViewController. Override the setMessageBody method. When user calls this method, store body into class variable(declared in your derived class). Use it when delegate method gets called.

Comment: but i can't access to user's text!